# Is it possible to hash password using c program before storing it in the MySQL database?

Tags: encryption, web-application, php, password-management, mysql

I am totally new to Web Development so this question might sound dumb. I've searched a lot to find a solution but had no success with it.

Currently, I am making a login page where I enter the password and verify it with the password already stored in the database for a successful login. I have an encryption algorithm which I wrote in C language and wanted to encrypt the password using this algorithm before verifying it with the password stored in the database (Password Hashing).

I am using PHP for retrieving the password and MySQL (phpMyAdmin) for storing it.

Is this even possible? If yes, how am I to do it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not really about information security but essentially only asks how to call some code written in C from PHP. What the code does is not relevant for the question.

Comment: You shouldn't encrypt passwords, you should hash them. Also, don't write your own hash algorithm. There are built in functions for password hashing in PHP. Read up on them and use them.

Comment: Thank you @Anders, the hash algorithm that I have written is MD5. I don't want to use the inbuilt functions, as I wanted to try out my code.

Comment: MD5 is completely, utterly broken. Do not use your own algorithm. Do not implement your own thing. Use one of bcrypt, scrypt, pdkdf2. Those are the only valid options for password hashing currently.

Comment: @VishistVVishy MD5 is completely broken for usage in passwords.  Search this website and you'll find many answers discussing why in detail.  Write your own function for practice if you want, but don't trust it for security.  **Only** use inbuilt functions in production.  Please read up on password security: right now it sounds like you're new to this, and you're putting your customers most important data at risk as a result